what's meant for $f:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ to be smooth(or, diffeomorphic)?
I'm referring to the differential geometry by Loring Tu page 10.
For smooth curve $c:[a,b]\to M$, we let $s(t) = \int^t_a \lVert c'(t)\rVert du$. Restricting $s$ to $[a,b]$ we get function $s:[a,b]\to [0,l]$, where $l$ is a length of the curve. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $s$ is a smooth function. I get what happens at $(a,b)$. But what happens on the edges?
In the book, the differentiability on the closed interval (for example $c$ above) means that there exists an open set covering that closed interval on which the function is smooth. But that is when the target space is a manifold $M$. It seems that in order for defining $s'(a)$ and $s'(b)$, we can either 1) extend the target space as well or 2) use the left/right limit.
For the record, the book uses inverse function theorem, saying that since $s$ is monotonically increasing smooth function, there exists a smooth inverse. I'm unsure how to apply inverse function theorem in this case because of what happens on the end points $a$ and $b$.
Could someone give me insight on this?

That target space is a smooth manifold though? It’s a smooth manifold with boundary so open sets are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ or the upper half plane $\mathbb H^n$. In this setting it’s a closed subset of $\mathn R$, and from an analysis perspective you should be comfortable with what it means to be smooth in such a set

@Chris True, but that means there exists a smooth curve $c^:(a', b')\to [c,d]$ where $(a,b)\subset (a', b')$. I think this contradicts the book since in my setting $c$ is monotonically increasing ($c(a)=c, c(b)=d$) and for $c^$ to be smooth in analysis setting the velocity at $a$ and $b$ should somehow "stop" but in my example this is not true ($c$ is regular)

no, if you extend the function on the domain then you might not land in the same codomain. The smooth structure on your target space is the same as one on your domain. If the extension of your function suddenly stops increasing at $b$ then your function can’t be smooth

@Chris "The smooth structure on your target space is the same as one on your domain" what do you mean? ...

To clarify, which one is true for $c:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ to be true? 1) $c:(a',b')\to (c',d')$ is smooth (extending both domain and codomain) 2) $c^*:(a',b')\to [c,d]$ is smooth (extending only the domain). Here $c$ is monotonically extending function with $c(a)=c, c(b)=d$ and the author says this is smooth..

Forget about that, the point is that the function $f$ can also just be viewed as a map from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$, so if you have a smooth extension (which you do by extending the curve smoothly) the map is smooth

@Chris I see, that makes sense. Is this a bit of abuse of notation to say $c:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and $c:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ is bijection at the same time? (I think I saw this somewhere on physics though)

It’s not an abuse of notation really, any continuous map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ can be viewed as a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow f(Y)$. Whether or not this map is smooth depends on whether $f(Y)$ has the structure of a smooth manifold

If $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively though, it doesn’t really matter that much because you can view the map as $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$, and the. $f$ is smooth if it admits a smooth extension to $\mathbb R^n$

@Chris Viewing $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ as manifolds with boundary, I can see that $c$ is indeed smooth for these smooth structures. But the author invokes inverse function theorem for $c$, while it seems the IVT can fail for smooth functions for manifolds with boundary, so I'm unsure if the author used this definition (confused)..

Inverse function theorem is something for smooth maps $f:V\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$. If $f$ is smooth and comes from a closed subset, then there’s a smooth extension such that the extension and all its derivatives agree on the closed subset (and the derivative at the boundary points are independent of the extension by continuity). You can use this extension to apply inverse function theorem in a neighborhood of the boundary, which by uniqueness of an inverse has to be your inverse on neighborhood of the image of a boundary point

@Chris Thank you so much. Everything makes sense to me now when I view $c$ as a map from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Great glad I could help

The smoothness makes sense, indeed, since $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ both have smooth structures as a manifold with boundary.
This is actually equivalent to saying that the extension $f':(a',b')\to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, where $f'=f$ on $[a,b]$.
Using this equivalence, we can use inverse function theorem on $f'$.
